# Scroll bar jumps back to the top when the hide link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Actually I have got a more number of records in my index page with respective "hide"link on each record. Then problem is when I click the respective link it hides the record but moves to the top of the page, how do I stop this?

_rak361.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Hide", hide_rak361_path(rak361), method: :put, class: 'stopper', style: "color:#ccc;" %>
```

ample.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".stopper").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

rak361s_controller.rb

```
def hide
        @rak361 = Rak361.find(params[:id])
        @rak361.hide
        flash[:notice] = 'Rak361 was successfully hidden.'
        redirect_to rak361s_url    
end
```

I have tried but it is not working for me.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use return false;

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried but not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Comment: Why are you not using path helpers in `link_to`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because its a full page reload, first thing you need to to do is to use `path helpers` instead of mentioning controller and action in `link_to`, and the second thing is you should use `remote: true` option to ajaxify the request. Here's an example

```
= link_to "Hide", example_hide_path(id), method: :put, remote: true, class: 'stopper', style: "color:#ccc;"
```

Either you can use `remote: true`, or you can send an ajax request using jQuery's `$.ajax()`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I updated my post as per your suggestion and I am not using any ajax in order to use "remote: true" option but still the issue persists.Please guide...

Comment: I just want to hide the records by clicking the hide link and retain there for any second hide.That's all.

Comment: Sir, waiting for your reply.

Comment: It is moving to the top because the request is not async, because of which the page is reloading. You can implement it via Ajax to avoid this. I can help you with that, may be we can move this conversation to chat. Let me know when you are available.

Comment: And I would definitely like to do it through Ajax.

Comment: Add remote: true to the link

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let's have the discussion in chat.